# JAX-WS trouble at handling the response message on the client side

Tags: java, jax-ws, soap-client, wsdl2java, wsimport

I am having some trouble with a client side implementation of a webservice. I have the wsdl and I have created the classes with the wsimport tool.

When I invoke the webservice via these classes I can see the request and and response in the log... and it looks ok. 
I can't use the classes to manipulate with the recieved data from the WS because the result object has no definition about the fields it contains...

Because of that I was trying to get the raw response from the WebService... I did this by attaching a SoapHandler:

```
BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider)port;
List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>();
handlerChain.add(new SoapMsgHandler());
bindingProvider.getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChain);

result = port.getXmlFromWS();
....
```

In the handler I implemented the handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) method to print the message to the log but I have encountered a problem...

Below is a piece of the Handler class that should handle the response... but I get an exception at this line: SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage()

The exception is the following:

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.insertBefore(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPDocument.appendChild(SOAPDocument.java:222)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPPartImpl.appendChild(SOAPPartImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.SAX2DOMEx.startElement(SAX2DOMEx.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.TagInfoset.writeStart(TagInfoset.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.stream.StreamMessage.writeTo(StreamMessage.java:442)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.readAsSOAPMessage(AbstractMessageImpl.java:193)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.SOAPMessageContextImpl.getMessage(SOAPMessageContextImpl.java:79)
```

Part of the handler implementation:

```
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

public class SoapMsgHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
  @Override
  public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    printTheMsg(context);
    return true;
  }

  private void printTheMsg(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
   SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();  //this line produces the mentioned exception
  ....
  }
  ....
 }
```

Any help about what might be wrong will be very appreciated.